# Create multiple instances of object with C++ and Openframeworks

Tags: c++, oop, openframeworks

I'm new to Openframeworks and C++, but not programming in general (PHP and Objective-C). I've created a class that draws a cube where the height, width and depth are variables. I'm attempting to create 3 versions of said class, each with different dimensions.

However, the first object's dimensions are being used for each instance. I attempted to switch the order of drawing, and no matter what, whatever is drawn first is used for all. Also, I cout the dimensions to the console and the correct dimensions are being sent, yet only the first version is drawn.

cube.h

```
#ifndef _CUBE
#define _CUBE

#include "ofMain.h"

class cube
{
public:

void update();
void draw();

cube(float _w, float _h, float _d);

float w;
float h;
float d;

ofMesh mesh;
ofVbo myVbo;


private:
};

#endif
```

cube.cpp

```
#include "cube.h"

cube::cube(float _w, float _h, float _d)
{
w = _w;
h = _h;
d = _d;

static GLfloat vdata[8][3] = {
    {-w, -h, -d}, {-w, h, -d},
    {w, h, -d}, {w, -h, -d},
    {-w, -h, d}, {w, -h, d},
    {-w, h, d}, {w, h, d}
};

static GLint indices[6][4] = {
    {3, 2, 1, 0},
    {3, 5, 4, 0},
    {3, 5, 7, 2},
    {0, 4, 6, 1},
    {1, 2, 7, 6},
    {5, 4, 6, 7}
};

ofColor color(ofRandom(255),ofRandom(255),ofRandom(255));
float hue = 254.f;

for (int i=0; i<8; ++i)
{
    mesh.addVertex(ofVec3f( vdata[i][0], vdata[i][1], vdata[i][2] ));
    mesh.addColor(color);
    color.setHue(hue);
    hue -= 20.f;

    for (int i=0; i<6; ++i)
    {
        mesh.addIndex(indices[i][0]);
        mesh.addIndex(indices[i][1]);
        mesh.addIndex(indices[i][2]);
        mesh.addIndex(indices[i][3]);
    }
}

myVbo.setMesh(mesh, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void cube::draw()
{
    myVbo.drawElements(GL_QUADS, 24);
}

void cube::update()
{

}
```

testApp.h

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "cube.h"

class testApp : public ofBaseApp{
public:
void setup();
void update();
void draw();

ofEasyCam camera;
cube *cube1;
cube *cube2;
cube *cube3;

void keyPressed(int key);
void keyReleased(int key);
void mouseMoved(int x, int y);
void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button);
void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button);
void mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button);
void windowResized(int w, int h);
void dragEvent(ofDragInfo dragInfo);
void gotMessage(ofMessage msg);
};
```

testApp.cpp

```
#include "testApp.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::setup()
{
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
ofBackground(33, 33, 33);

cube1 = new cube(50, 100, 25);
cube2 = new cube(300, 50, 80);
cube3 = new cube(250, 160, 30);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::update()
{

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::draw()
{
camera.begin();

cube1->draw();

ofPushMatrix();
ofTranslate(40, 60);
cube2->draw();
ofPopMatrix();

ofPushMatrix();
ofTranslate(80, 100);
cube3->draw();
ofPopMatrix();
}

/*other code*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After combing the code and testing out different things, I found the fix. I simply dropped the `static` from `GFloat` and `GLint` arrays. I still don't understand why completely, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I cannot post comment as I do not have enough reputation. 
I was not able to find error in code by reading, so I quickly gave it a run in OF and as you can see...[image]

no problem in here... I am running OF 0.8 on VS2012Express - Win7 i7 nVidia Quatro 4000.

EDIT: maybe it is compiler issue? I had such a problem with addons that could not even compile. But that is just a wild guess...

EDIT: I just noticed that antony answered his own question, when I finally figured out why it was happening. I cannot still cannot add comments, so...
 Thing is that values of `static` variables are all identical for all instances of class. There are more stuff to it, but generally, if you change static variable (let's say `static int width`) in one object, change will occur in all of them.

And here is how it should look like :)

[image]

Comment: I would like each cube to be a different size. 50x100x25, 300x50x80, and 250x160x30 respectively. Yet, they are all 50x100x25.